# In Oracle, Covert Timestamp to Number

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In oracle database, I have a table with one column for "**Update date**" having data type as Timestamp (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM).

I want to convert this timestamp into a number, including the Hour, Minute and Seconds part.

Anyone please suggest what should be my query to get the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rajat Arora

Comment: why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: not required on other planets yet I guess!

Comment: and how would a timestamp of '01/01/2015 14:34:23.555555` be represented as a number? You forgot to include that in your question.

Comment: I haven't include because I am not considering milliseconds in my case. Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: You want this: `select to_char(systimestamp, 'hh24miss')+0 from dual` ?

Comment: Thanks Ponder for the solution, but I wanted that along with the date. I got the solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Solution query---

Select
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
From
       dual;

Answer (score 1):

Solution query---

Select 
     TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(Timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) 
From 
     dual;